# Copy div content on button click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to copy the div content on button click.

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {

const copyCode = () => {
    //TODO
}

const data = "www.test.com";

const srcCode = `<script src=${data}></script>`;


return (
    <>
    <div>
      {srcCode}
    </div>
    <button onClick={copyCode}>
        Copy
    </button>
    </>
);
}
```

export default App;

Comment: copy to clipboard or just get the value?

Comment: I just want to get the value and paste somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This could be simple using [react-copy-to-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard) library

```js
const data = "www.test.com";
const srcCode = `<script src=${data}></script>`;

return (
  <>
    <div>{srcCode}</div>
    <br />
    <CopyToClipboard text={srcCode} onCopy={() => alert("copied")}>
      <button>Copy</button>
    </CopyToClipboard>
  </>
);
```

Codesandbox for demo

[image: Edit cold-cherry-074yh]